# Yii or ZendFramework? [+ORM]

Tags: zend-framework, orm, yii, php

I'm wondering which PHP framework to use. I've used CodeIgniter for my projects, but when version 2.0 released, I understood that it isn't what I need, because it's still old CI and only few small features were added.

Currently I can't decide which framework to use: Zend or Yii. And also I need some ORM tool (built-in in framework or external).
I found this small discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667382/which-php-framework-should-i-choose-between-zendframework-and-yii
But this discussion is relatively old. And a lot of things could change in two years.

I need stability, good documentation/books and good performance because I don't plan to use framework for programming small personal blogs. :)

So which one I should learn and use?

P.S. Sorry for my poor English skills.

P.P.S. May be you could offer me some other PHP-framework?

Comment: What about Kohana (http://kohanaframework.org)?

Comment: @biakaverson Kohana's documentation is now much better than it was with version <= 3.0.x, but it's still not enough... It's well-written framework but unfortunately it's to dynamic for me to use it and there's not very much documentation and no books about it yet. That's one of the reasons why I can't use it yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Zend Framework don't have build in ORM. If you want to use ORM look into doctrine2, or for high-load - mongodb (nosql).
2. ZF is stable but not very fast.
3. Documentation is not very good, some things you can find only in source code.

Yii is high-perfomance.
Yii has own implementation of ORM called Yii Active Record(AR).
Yii documentation is pretty good.

For new experience I'll try Yii, but in you case is hard to decide.

Comment: ZF has API docs, a multilingual reference guide and a wiki. If you think this is not sufficient documentation then go the Issue Tracker and tell them what is missing. Tutorials are not documentation.

Comment: Simply: ZF docs not discribes strict techniques how to develope. ZF is hard to start study.

Comment: There is a *Getting Started* in the reference manual. In addition to the various tutorials and articles ZF advertises through their RSS feed and the various contributors have put on their blogs.

Comment: @Gordon in general i like ZF))

Comment: The Active Record pattern is *not* the same as ORM

Answer (score -4):

Personally I use [CakePHP](http://www.cakephp.org).
The documentation is just awesome.

I've never really understood the use for Zend in more use-cases.
It takes long to set up and you can import the Zend library functions in pretty much any other framework (including CakePHP and Yii). So using frameworks with a faster development cycle with Zend libraries imported just seems like the logical thing to do.

Comment: Does it have an ORM built-in module/extension or you prefer to use some other ORM tool or just write plain SQL? And what about Cake's performance?

Comment: CakePHP has ORM built in and ready to roll out of the box. There are plenty of benchmarks online that compare frameworks. Cake seems to do fine in those. Yii looks like it's really damn fast, but I've never been too worried about performance. As long as the speeds remain usable it's not a huge concern for me.

Comment: @Gordon How is Active Record not an ORM implementation in CakePHP's case?

Comment: Let me rephrase that: [Active Record may be used to implement ORM, but it should never be used as an ORM.](http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/why_active_record_sucks.html)

Comment: @Gordon There are some good points in there. As with all premade solutions to your problems though, it's really dependant on your use-case. AR still seems like a good way to deal with data for small/medium projects that can live with the cons of AR or can work around them without getting too messy. If the cons of AR are a big deal, you can look at frameworks that allow the usage of other ORM implementations such as Doctrine. I believe both Yii and Zend have the ability to work with Doctrine without too much work.